# Assigning a value to an appending html table with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, cakephp

Hi im adding a label and a text field to a table every time the button is clicked but im also trying to give each label an incremented value but I keep getting an Unexpected identifier error. The code is as follows:

```
var counter = 2;

$('.addButton').click(function()
{
    $('#existingRow').after($('<tr><td><?php $cou = 2; echo $this->Form->label('Option' + $cou + ':');  $cou++ ?></td><td><?php echo $this->Form->input('name', array('label' => '', 'style' => 'height: 10px; width: 150px;')); ?></td></tr>'));
    counter++;
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are mixing up your php and javascript.

Comment: Ye ive edited my code now to just php variables and i dont get errors anymore but instead of printing out Option 2: it just prints out 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't use JS variable counter inside PHP code block. Try:

```
var counter = 2;

$('.addButton').click(function()
{
   $('#existingRow').append('<tr><td>labelname' +  counter + ':'</td><td><?php echo $this->Form->input('name', array('label' => '', 'style' => 'height: 10px; width: 150px;')); ?></td></tr>');
   counter++;
});
```

If it works, instead of labelname you can then insert here whatever is generated with

```
 echo $this->Form->label('Option 2:');
```

and then change 2 with counter in JS

Comment: Yes it works with labelname' +  counter + but how do i get this to work inside echo $this->Form->label('OHere'); inside this?

Comment: first do `echo $this->Form->label('OHere');` somewere, and see what html was generated in browsers source code, copy this html in place of labelname and replace `OHere` with `OHere' + counter + '`

Comment: First I changed OHere with word Option

Secondly all that prints out now is Option + counter + :

This was the generated html code:

<label for="VariableOption">Option + counter + :</label>

Comment: Oh sorry i done something completely stupid it works Thanks very much for your help question solved :)

Comment: I'm happy I could help ;) reg.

Answer (score 1):

The error you get is because you are using these lines as identifier in $() selector. i.e. $('`<tr><td><?php echo $this->Form->label('Option '+ counter + ':'); ?></td><td><?php echo $this->Form->input('name', array('label' => '', 'style' => 'height: 10px; width: 150px;')); ?></td></tr>`'). The code in gray is taken as an identifier.

My suggestion is to create an element of table row using document.createElement. Here is the complete code.

in html file you should have a table

```
<table id="my-table"></table>
```

in you javascript file

```
var counter = 2;
$('.addButton').click(function()
{
    tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tr.innerHTML = "<td><?php echo $this->Form->label('Option '+ counter + ':'); ?></td><td><?php echo $this->Form->input('name', array('label' => '', 'style' => 'height: 10px; width: 150px;')); ?></td>";
    $('#my-table').append(tr);
    counter++;
});
```

It will surely do the trick.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to fix it and place my counter?

Comment: Try that and hopefully no error will occur. If it occurs then post the error here.

Comment: sorry I forgot to insert a hash(#) sign in `$('my-table')`. Write it as `$('#my-table')`.

Comment: Ye i picked up on that already and inserted it myself but still same error.

Comment: ok. Let's just cut it down into small chunks.

`tr = document.createElement('tr');`
`html = "<td><?php echo $this->Form->label('Option " + counter + ":'); ?></td>";`
`html += "";`
`html += "<td><?php echo $this->Form->input('name', array('label' => '', 'style' => 'height: 10px; width: 150px;')); ?></td>"`
`tr.innerHTML = html;`
`$('#my-table').append(tr);`

Comment: You don't need to be sorry. Can you tell me the solution so I can answer better to future questions.

Comment: Ive written a post supplying the answer i think its at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Here is answer for anyone looking:

```
    var counter = 2;

$('.addButton').click(function()
{
    $('#existingRow').before($('<tr><td><label for="VariableOption">Option' + counter + ':</label></td><td><?php echo $this->Form->input('name', array('label' => '', 'style' => 'height: 10px; width: 150px;')); ?></td></tr>'));
    counter++;
});
```

Thanks to @grzegorz_motyl